# Different behaviour between Android and Iphone with template flyout Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

When creating a new Xamarin.Forms App with the template "flyout" I get the expected behaviour on my Android Simulator [Android Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIRzh.png) but the same code when deployed on my Iphone Simulator doesn't show the tab bar and the flyout. They still are there, meaning that if I press the screen where the tabs and the flyout should be, I get the expected behavoiur, but the screen doesn't show these items [Iphone Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CqCz.png). I am using Visual Studio 2019, the  Android Simulator is "Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 - API 28 (Android 9.0 - API 28)" while the Iphone Simulator is "Iphone 11 iOS 15.2"

Comment: According to you, I created a flyout template and tried to run it in Android and iOS, the result is displayed normally in Android and the bottom bar does not appear. Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: Here a minimal project https://github.com/adrilang/ItemsApp/tree/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS it is because there is no color on your Tabbar.

You can add on **itemsApp->AppDelegate.cs->FinishedLaunching** method:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
{
    UITabBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
    UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
    UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
}
```

The complete method for FinishedLaunching is:

```
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
        {
            UITabBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
            UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
        }

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Comment: Great thanks. The upper hamburger menu and the titles are still not visible, but I guess I can handle them in a similar way.

Comment: Just need to add UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;  I have updated my code.